# Cancelling pull to refresh in ios once it started

Tags: ios, pull-to-refresh

I've implemented pull to refresh and it is working, the issue I'm having is once the refresh started I cannot cancel it by dragging the screen up. Any ideas how to cancel pull to refresh once it started? Thanks!

Comment: How did you add refreshing? Ending it depends on that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can end refreshing by:        `refreshControl!.endRefreshing()`